# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at `localhost:...` - ExpressJS and npm Cors

Tags: javascript, express, cors

I got the error **Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at `localhost:...`** with my examples code below, how can I fix it?, I just follow any guides in docs and stackoverflow but no one working.

I'm using cors module from npm.

```js
// Init express application
const app = express();

// Setup cors for cross domain requests
const whitelist = [
  "http://localhost:3002/", // frontend curr localhost port
  "http://localhost:5500/", // live server url
];
// eslint-disable-next-line
const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    // allow if the origin is undefined,
    // means has the same origin, the result
    // is undefined because the request
    // is coming from the same origin.
    if (!origin) return callback(null, true);

    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error("CORS not allowed"));
    }
  },
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
  methods: ["GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
  credentials: true, //Credentials are cookies, authorization headers or TLS client certificates.
  allowedHeaders: [
    "Content-Type",
    "Authorization",
    "X-Requested-With",
    "device-remember-token",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "Origin",
    "Accept",
  ],
};

app.options("*", cors(corsOptions));
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
// END SECURITY CONFIG

// Route for monolithic app
const web = require("./routes/web");
// Route for microservices app
const api = require("./routes/api");
// Route for unit testing
const test = require("./routes/test");
```

Comment: You can always just cheat and use the CORS npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: The OP is using the `cors` npm package. It's not an issue with configuring and supporting CORS; it's the web browser's security model that is disallowing CORS requests to a localhost resource.

Answer (score 3):

You can't fix this issue in code. It's a configuration issue for your network architecture, and your webbrowser is enforcing proper security.

For quite some time webbrowsers default to not allowing CORS for localhost.

The incorrect work-around is to disable CORS checking in your webbrowser. For Chrome it was adding the `--disable-web-security` to the program executable, i.e. creating a chrome shortcut (Windows) to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security`.

The correct way to resolve this is to not have your client code running on the webbrowser connect to your api server using localhost, and instead properly configure your environment to expose the server over a hostname.

There are a myriad of ways to do this depending on how you are running your server and clients, but if you are simply running your client and server on the same machine for development and debugging, you should only need to add an entry to your to your [hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) file that resolves a hostname in addition to localhost to 127.0.0.1.

Then update your code to whitelist test.mydomain.com

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 test.mydomain.com
```